# Adding integers in a list

Tags: python

I am attempting to add integers that are originally in a string (for example `num = "657647"`).

I converted the integers in to ints by using a for loop and converting everyone of them.

The result is a list? Think that's 6 5 7 6 4 7, with each number on a new line.

At first I was under the impression that its a list that I can iterate over, but apparently not.

This is an example code of what I am trying to do:

```
def addingNumbers(string):
  double_numbers =""
  theSum = 0

  for i in range(0,7) :
    convertingInt = int(string[i])
    theSum += convertingInt
    print theSum
```

If i enter the string 8101818, i want the sum to be just 27 but instead it is printing the following:

```
>>> addingNumbers("8101818")
8
9
9
10
18
19
27
```

I know that the problem is that the code is adding the previous numbers separately but I want it to be just one total number, so in my case 27.

How do I do this?

Comment: Also try `print sum(int(i) for i in string)`

Comment: Paul's implementation is not only simpler, it doesn't assume the string has 7 digits.

Answer (score 2):

> If i enter the string 8101818, i want the sum to be just 27

In python, indentation matters.

```
def addingNumbers(string):
  double_numbers =""
  theSum = 0

  for i in range(0,7) :
    convertingInt = int(string[i])
    theSum += convertingInt
  print theSum
```

remove a level of indentation from your print line as I did in the above code and it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I overlooked the indentation completely.

Answer (score 1):

one line to achieve the target can be done like this:

```
a = "8101818"
print sum(map(int,a))
```

Comment: is there also a way to do that but store the value instead of printing it? thanks. never mind, figured it out

Comment: just assign the value to a variable, like `total = sum(map(int,a))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below if you want to modify your code but what Hooting gave is very pythonic,

```
str = "8101818"

for i in str:
    sum = sum + int(i)

print sum
27
```

Answer (score 0):

Your print is inside the loop so it will print it each time. Try removing it from the loop and it will work.